# Selenium WebDriver C#: How to get test execution results report in NUnit framework?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am using an NUnit framework for Selenium WebDriver C#.
Does NUnit provide any default test results report, similar to that provided by TestNG in Java?

Answer (score 0):

NUnit provides output information in the form of an XML file.

Beyond that, it depends on how you are running your tests. Each runner may give you a different way to access that file and may give you reports as well. So, any true answer requires more info from you as to how you run your tests.

If you update your question, I'll try to update my answer. :-)

Comment: I run my test from Test Explorer. Right click on the test and select 'Run'.